# How can I pass a collection of delegates to be run into a method

Tags: c#, .net

Referencing the sample below, is there a way to pass the work done by GetType1s() and GetType2s() in on this constructor?  I'm looking for something along the lines of a List`<Action>` so that I can just run each action iteratively from within the constructor without caring about what it does, but I can't think of an appropriate way to do that in which variables are set (and of different types).  I realize this is getting awfully close to DI and IOC, so maybe there's no way out of creating a container if I want to pass this work into the class like this?

```
      public MainPageViewModel(string taskBaseLocation)
    {
        TasksBaseLocation = taskBaseLocation;
        Type1List = TasksModel.GetType1s(TasksBaseLocation);
        Type2List = TasksModel.GetType2s(TasksBaseLocation);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an appropriate delegate type and pass that in a generic list.

```
public delegate retType MyDelegate(param1type param1, param2type param2,...)

List<MyDelegate> listToPass = new List<MyDelegate>();
```

Comment: Yup, that did it.  Just call each action in a loop after adding them like so :    listOfStartupActions.Add(new StartupAction(delegate(string o) { Events = TasksModel.GetType1s(o); }));

Answer (score 2):

Since delegates are multicast, just pass an `Action`:

```
if(action != null) { action(); }
```

and combine at the caller.

If you need to run them independently (for example, to run later actions even if earlier actions fail), de-construct it:

```
if(action != null)
{
    foreach(Action child in action.GetInvocationList())
    {
        try
        {
            child();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             // handle/log etc
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this doesn't magically provide access to the member variables from the delegate, unless the delegate's context *already* had access to the fields (and a reference to the new instance, perhaps via `Action<T>` instead of `Action`)

Comment: Thanks!  I went w/ Odeds solution, it was closest to what I had in mind, however I like this approach as well.  I was overly hung up on the notion that Action's dont return values, but in the end neither do my delegates since the property setting is internal to the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches here, using pure lambdas or using Delegate.Combine. I'd prefer the lambda variety.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace X
{
    public class MyType
    {
        public delegate void DoInitialize(MyType instance);
        public int a,b,c;

        public MyType(DoInitialize initialize) 
        {
            initialize(this);
        }

        public MyType(params Action<MyType>[] initializers) 
        {
            foreach (var initializer in initializers)
                initializer(this);
        }

        public static void LambdaApproach()
        {
            var instance = new MyType(
                    i => i.a = 1,
                    i => i.b = 2,
                    i => i.c = 42);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", instance.a, instance.b, instance.c);
        }

        public static void MulticastApproach()
        {
            var lambdas = new DoInitialize[] {
                    i => i.a = 1,
                    i => i.b = 2,
                    i => i.c = 42, };

            var instance = new MyType((DoInitialize) Delegate.Combine(lambdas.ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", instance.a, instance.b, instance.c);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LambdaApproach();
            MulticastApproach();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't used Delegate.Combine before, but I like it.  :)